# Unable To Stop Individual SQL Dependencies On Form Close

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqldependency

I am very new to SQL Dependencies and found this is a great way to handle data updating within my application.  Previously I was constantly querying my Database every minute or so to check for changes, whereas now I receive update notifications on change events as they occur.

When my application first launches, it starts the SQL Dependency to the database with: `SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString)` and in turn Stops it once I exit.

I then setup about 3 or 4 dependency queries to receive updates for different data within my application - all works great and exactly how I need.

**However, my issue is this:**
I have a second form of which I call multiple instances of.  This form also has about 3 different dependencies attached to update different data again. However, when I close the instance of the form, I am finding that the dependency continues to run and thus throws an error in my application due to the form now being closed.

**My question is:** Is there a way I can stop the individual SQL Dependencies once I close the form?  The dependencies on the Main form should continue to run, but every time I open and close an instance of the second form, I need to stop and start those queries from running.

Is this possible?

I can provide sample code snippets if required.

Any help appreciated.  Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up resolving this issue myself after a little bit of thought and researching.
Previously, I was declaring the SQLDependency within the same Sub Routine as the Handler like so:

```
Private Sub RefreshRegisterData()
    ...
    Dim Register_dep As SqlDependency
    Register_dep = New SqlDependency(cmd)
    AddHandler Register_dep.OnChange, AddressOf Registers_OnChange
    ...
End Sub
```

However, to resolve my issue I basically moved the scope of the SQLDependency outside of the Sub Routine and declared it globally within the Class:

```
Public Class frmStorePage
    Private Register_dep As SqlDependency
    ...

    Private Sub RefreshRegisterData()
        ...
        Register_dep = New SqlDependency(cmd)
        AddHandler Register_dep.OnChange, AddressOf Registers_OnChange
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, when exiting my form, I simply implemented a RemoveHandler call to stop the message queue and destroy the existing handler:

```
Private Sub frmStorePage_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    RemoveHandler Register_dep.OnChange, AddressOf Registers_OnChange
    ...
End Sub
```

Now, not sure if this is the preferred method of solving this issue, however, I am yet to witness any implications by this code and it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Stop method in the SqlDependency class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency_methods(v=vs.90).aspx) that you can invoke when you are done listening. Is there some issue with this?

ADDED

According to the docs, "Stops a listener for a connection specified in a previous Start call."

So, thhough I have not ever done exactly this, it should work if you are using a different connections in the main and child forms.

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I call the .Stop method once I exit my application.  If I call it once I exit the second form, won't that stop all SQL Dependencies running on the Main form?